# CircuitBreakerOpenException when running unit test

Tags: quarkus

When changing to Quarkus 2.6.2.Final I suddenly run into: `org.eclipse.microprofile.faulttolerance.exceptions.CircuitBreakerOpenException` (circuit breaker is open) when running (unit / integration) test annotated with `@QuarkusTest`.

I changed other stuff except the Quarkus baseline, so I don't know for sure the update is the sole cause.

```java
@Path( "/" )
@Retry( delay = 250L, maxRetries = 5 )
@Timeout( 5000L )
@CircuitBreaker( requestVolumeThreshold = 5 )
@Slf4j
public class OrganizationsResource {
// ...
}
```

I guess that the circuit breaker should not be active during testing to facilitate negative testing.

Increasing the threshold to 10 solved it. Disabling the faulttolerance feature while running test would be better IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not caused by the update, Quarkus 2.6.2.Final did not change anything regarding the fault tolerance stuff.

To facilitate negative testing, you can inject `CircuitBreakerMaintenance` and reset all circuit breakers in the application using `resetAll` (see https://smallrye.io/docs/smallrye-fault-tolerance/5.2.1/usage/extra.html#_circuit_breaker_maintenance).

Alternatively, there's a configuration property that disables all fault tolerance except fallbacks: `MP_Fault_Tolerance_NonFallback_Enabled` (see https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-fault-tolerance-3.0/microprofile-fault-tolerance-spec-3.0.html#_disable_a_group_of_fault_tolerance_annotations_on_the_global_level).

Comment: I did try the first option and that does not work. But, I noticed something. The testcase that fails throws an custom runtime exception. Running the test case individually fails as well.  The `requestVolumeThreshold  = 5`. Change to: `requestVolumeThreshold  = 10` and the testcase passes. But how can an individual exception trigger this? I would at least expect 5 exceptions thrown before the breaker to hit.

Comment: What you describe sounds very unlikely, on its own, but if you can isolate a reproducer, please file an issue and I'll take a look.

Comment: I'll do my best to make one soon..

Comment: https://github.com/sjaakd/reproducer_circuit_breaker but.. I found the issue. It's the combination: `@Retry( delay = 250L, maxRetries = 5 )
@Timeout( 5000L )
@CircuitBreaker( requestVolumeThreshold = 10 )`. The maxRetries causes the attempt to be retried 5 times and voila, the circuitbreaker flips open.

Comment: Note: the requestVolumeThreshold was 5 (copy-paste error in comment above) and somewhere along the line this behavior did changed after going to Quarkus 2.6.2. Testcases testing exceptional behavior started to fail.

Comment: Ah that's a great point, I totally missed that. Glad you found the problem.